# Can't save Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, tableview, simperium

I tried saving core data in tableview with NSFetchedResultsController and different sections.

When I add data following error appears:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  ***
>   -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0] with userInfo (null)**
>    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' **-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0] ***
>
> First throw call stack: (0x181a05900 0x181073f80 0x1818f41a8 0x1818f4040 0x1000a9068 0x1000aa8d8 0x1835905a8 0x183505080
>   0x183504f48 0x183495108 0x1819aafc4 0x1819aa7e4 0x1819aa564
>   0x181a0fde4 0x1818eb0f4 0x1822dad2c 0x18349506c 0x1835098d0
>   0x18349378c 0x183492240 0x1000aa3a0 0x18672fe50 0x1868b34a4
>   0x18672fe50 0x18672fdcc 0x186717a88 0x186717bd4 0x18672f6e4
>   0x18672f314 0x186727e30 0x1866f84cc 0x1866f6794 0x1819bcefc
>   0x1819bc990 0x1819ba690 0x1818e9680 0x182df8088 0x186760d90
>   0x10004c23c 0x18148a8b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException`

My code:

```
MyDetailData* MyDetail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyDetailData" inManagedObjectContext:self._privateObjectContext];
[MyDetail setKategorie: NSLocalizedString(@"Test", nil)];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![MyDetail.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

under iOS6 all was fine with that code

Here is my NSFetchedResultsController

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController2 {

    if (fetchedResultsController2 != nil) {
       return fetchedResultsController2;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription     entityForName:@"MyDetailData" inManagedObjectContext:_privateObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *KategorieDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"kategorie" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *oderDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:KategorieDescriptor,oderDescriptor,nameDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:_privateObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"kategorie" cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController2 = aFetchedResultsController;

    return fetchedResultsController2;

}
```

TableView delegates

- numberOfSectionsInTableView
- numberOfRowsInSection
- NSFetchedResultsController didChangeObject ->
  NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert
- NSFetchedResultsController didChangeSection ->
  NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert

called and contain right information - here is relevant code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[fetchedResultsController2 sections] count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController2 sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    if (userDrivenDataModelChange) return;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
            [self configureCell:[self.tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSString *sectionKeyPath = [controller sectionNameKeyPath];
            if (sectionKeyPath == nil)
                break;

            NSManagedObject *changedObject = [controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSArray *keyParts = [sectionKeyPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            id currentKeyValue = [changedObject valueForKeyPath:sectionKeyPath];
            for (int i = 0; i < [keyParts count] - 1; i++) {
                NSString *onePart = [keyParts objectAtIndex:i];
                changedObject = [changedObject valueForKey:onePart];
            }
            sectionKeyPath = [keyParts lastObject];
            NSDictionary *committedValues = [changedObject committedValuesForKeys:nil];

            if ([[committedValues valueForKeyPath:sectionKeyPath] isEqual:currentKeyValue])
                break;

            NSUInteger tableSectionCount = [self.tv numberOfSections];
            NSUInteger frcSectionCount = [[controller sections] count];
            if (tableSectionCount != frcSectionCount) {
                // Need to insert a section
                NSArray *mysections = controller.sections;
                NSInteger newSectionLocation = -1;
                for (id oneSection in mysections) {
                    NSString *sectionName = [oneSection name];
                    if ([currentKeyValue isEqual:sectionName]) {
                        newSectionLocation = [mysections indexOfObject:oneSection];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (newSectionLocation == -1)
                    return; // uh oh

                if (!((newSectionLocation == 0) && (tableSectionCount == 1) && ([self.tv numberOfRowsInSection:0] == 0)))
                    [self.tv insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newSectionLocation] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSUInteger indices[2] = {newSectionLocation, 0};
                newIndexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndexes:indices length:2];
            }


        }

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:NO];
            [self.tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:NO];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            if (!((sectionIndex == 0) && ([self.tv numberOfSections] == 1)))
                [self.tv insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            if (!((sectionIndex == 0) && ([self.tv numberOfSections] == 1) ))
                [self.tv deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: 
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: could you add the request code please

Comment: The crucial information is `[__NSPlaceholderDictionary ... init ... attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]`

Comment: @vadian what should it mean.

Comment: Somewhere something tries to initialize a dictionary with a `nil` object which is not allowed.

Comment: @  BEN MESSAOUD Mahmoud i relevant code for you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 
in

```
didChangeObject
```

at

```
 case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove
```

i changed the line

```
 [self.tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:NO];

  [self.tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                           withRowAnimation:NO];
```

to

```
   if (indexPath && newIndexPath) {
                 [self.tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:NO];

                 [self.tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                           withRowAnimation:NO];
  } else {
                 NSLog(@"A table item was moved");
  }
```